# Sitecore 8: Number of Recipients in List Manager not calculating properly

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

In List Manager 'Recipients' field values are sometimes not getting calculated correctly. For some lists it shows 0 but when I go inside to that contact list there are contacts.

[image]

I have followed the steps below:

1. Rebuild sitecore_list_index
2. Rebuild all Sitecore indexes
3. Rebuild all Sitecore indexes and restart the site and the app pool of the site in IIS

But still the issue is not solved.

Comment: This is the case for all my lists in the List Manage, I believe this is a genuine issue in Sitecore

Comment: Guess then we have to raise a Sitecore support ticket for this issue.

Answer (score -2):

I have the same issue. What could be really helpful - you can edit "Recipients" field of your List Item in Content Editor.

All list items are based here: /sitecore/system/List Manager/All Lists/

Comment: Artiom, in the future, please post this as a comment than you get the privilege. This is not an answer.