# Recipient Count incorrect in List Manager on Sitecore 8.0

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I'm facing a issue in list manager. Recipients count is incorrect in list manager . Can anyone know how the recipient count is generated?
(Are there any Lucene index related to generating the recipient count )

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33560587/sitecore-8-number-of-recipients-in-list-manager-not-calculating-properly

Comment: This is an issue with Sitecore, it has been raised with their Support so should be resolved by them in a patch or in the next release